# Как получить программно имя картинки?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

Картинки в asset, загружаю в приложение с помощью цикла. 
Получаю вначале номера из строковых рессурсов, затем вставляю их в название картинок `"img"+filT+".jpg"`
Сам код загрузки картинок

```
        int filT = filename2.getId();
        ///////
        // Использование AssetManager для загрузки следующего изображения
        AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = assets.open("img"+filT+".jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // загружаем как Drawable
        Drawable flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);
        // выводим картинку в ImageView
        flagImageView.setImageDrawable(flag);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Картинки загружаются в кнопки ImageButton

```
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button"
                 .../>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                 .../>
```

Картинки загружаются случайным образом.
Как можно при нажатии на кнопку программно получить название картинки и записать в string, например при нажатии получить что-то типа `img4.jpg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) и [getTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag()) для картинки, а потом для imageButton

> Получаю вначале номера из строковых рессурсов, затем вставляю их в
>   название картинок "img"+filT+".jpg"

тут же установите `setTag()` картинке с этим названием.

Слушатель

```
imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        String imageName = (String) view.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(this, imageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};);
```

Comment: Я само изображение загружаю таким образом flagImageView.setImageDrawable(flag); соответственно в flag случайная картинки, каким образом вставить тег .setTag("img4.jpg");?

Comment: @Artsait: как вы вставляете название в картинку? обновил ответ

Comment: getTag в flagImageView.setTag(flag.getTag()); не хочет срабатывать, красным цветом

Comment: @Artsait: реально выложить весь активити-код? скорее всего, да, я не прав, с drawable.getTag()