# ImageButton как при нажатии получить название картинки?

Tags: java, android, imagebutton, onclicklistener

Обработчик нажатия кнопки

```
private View.OnClickListener guessButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageButton guessButton = ((ImageButton) v);
```

Имя нужно как-то получить из guessButton и записать в `String`, все перепробовал, не получается.

Comment: В картинке нету названия, очевидно

Comment: зачем два [одинаковых вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782980/177345)?